# yii framework no such file in directory

Tags: php, yii

Recently, I've tried to install an application which requires a yii framework.
Unfortunately, it seems like it can't find the yii.php file located in my framework directory, and therefore giving me an internal server error.

I've searched for an answer for a really long time, without any result. I'm pretty sure that both the directory and the files are in there.

The error:

```
PHP Warning:  require_once(/home/site/public_html/framework/yii.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /home/site/public_html/index.php on line 15
PHP Fatal error:  require_once(): Failed opening required '/home/site/public_html/framework/yii.php' (include_path='.:/usr/lib/php:/usr/local/lib/php') in /home/site/public_html/index.php on line 15
```

index.php:

```
// change the following paths if necessary
$yii=dirname(__FILE__).'/framework/yii.php';
$config=dirname(__FILE__).'/application/config/web.php';

if(!is_readable($config))
    exit('Missing configuration file. Please run the <a href="./install">installation</a>.');

// remove the following lines when in production mode
defined('YII_DEBUG') or define('YII_DEBUG',true);
// specify how many levels of call stack should be shown in each log message
defined('YII_TRACE_LEVEL') or define('YII_TRACE_LEVEL',3);

require_once($yii);
Yii::createWebApplication($config)->run();
```

I have also CHMODDED the directory (777) but without any result.
Help is appreciated.

Comment: are you sure that file  `/home/site/public_html/framework/yii.php` exist?

Comment: can you show your directory struct?

Comment: @excluded_once http://prntscr.com/51odme

Comment: what the site directory after home? in screnshot i cant see no site directory... have you trying to var_damp $yii to see the pass what lay there?

Answer (score 1):

The path in your question is /home/site/public_html/framework/yii.php
But in the picture, i saw: /home/mbbclanv/...... This is wrong.

Answer (score 0):

if you are sure file exist and the path is correct try this

```
chmod -R 777 /home/site/public_html/
```

`-R` to provide permission recursively.